# Performance of function declaration vs function expressions in javascript in a loop

Tags: javascript, performance

In the following jsperf: http://jsperf.com/defined-function-vs-in-loop-function/3

You will notice that this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
   function func(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  };
  func(i, i);
}
```

Performs on par with this code:

```
function declaredFn(a, b) {
    return a + b;
};


for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
    declaredFni, i);
}
```

But this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
  var func = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  };
  func(i, i);
}
```

is significantly slower then this code:

```
var expfunc = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
};
for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {  
  expfunc(i, i);
}
```

Why? What is happening internally?

Answer (score 8):

If you define a function using the `function fn() {}` declaration, it gets hoisted to the top. Therefore, this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
   function func(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  };
  func(i, i);
}
```

is *exactly equivalent* to this code:

```
function declaredFn(a, b) { return a + b; };

for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) { declaredFn(i, i); }
```

because the `function` declaration gets hoisted to the top.

However, `var fn = function() {}` expressions *do not* get hoisted, so you end up defining the function all over on every single loop.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/336868/3371119) for more info.

Comment: It seems to depend on the JS implementation. The test shows that for FireFox it is significantly slower then other versions.

Comment: @freakish That's probably because Firefox supports a third type of function creation: function statements. They behave the same as function expressions, so they're created within the loop, not before.

Comment: But wouldn't your function statement be a function declaration on any system not supporting the function-statement-extension? In this case it would be a wrong place for a function definition since it's only allowed in `Program`- or `FunctionBody`-Level.

Comment: @delbertooo Yes that's true. It's wrong in theory but not in practice because most (some) browsers support it (unless you turn on strict mode -- if you turn on strict mode, then declaring a function in a loop using `function fn(){}` method will give a syntax error).

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet

```
for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
  var func = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  };
  func(i, i);
}
```

you are assigning a function to a variable, which will be available in the rest of the current scope. As you are doing this in a loop, the function is defined and assigned many times, therefore consuming more time than in the other cases you mentioned.

Comment: "you are assigning a function to a variable" --- even if you remove assignment performance will stay the same

Comment: I don't think (but didn't test it), that performance will stay exactly the same, but I guess you are right, that the function definition takes much longer.

Comment: "I don't think (but didn't test it), that performance will stay exactly the same" --- well, try then

Comment: Sry, didn't really think, when I wrote my last comment: If you remove the assignment, the function is declared only once, if you assign it to a variable, it's defined in every single loop. So it's substantially different code and performance does not stay the same.

Comment: it's not an assignment that is slow since assignment is virtually free. Convert it to IIFE, there will be no assignment but it will be slow.

Comment: Cause if you use a selfexecuting-anonymous-function the definition will be executed every time, as no function is declared, which is available in the current scope.

Comment: it will be executed multiple times not because it's IIFE, and not because of there is an assignment, but because it's a function expression. This statement "you are assigning a function to a variable ... s you are doing this in a loop" is basically incorrect.